# Why drop the “i” in “explanation”?

Tags: orthography, suffixes, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I often catch myself trying to write ?*expla**i**nation*, phonetically spelling the word in my head. To my chagrin I get part way through and have to stop myself.

So I’m wondering why is the *i* dropped? I can’t think of other words ending *‑ain* that take the *‑ation* suffix for comparison.

Comment: At least you're not Ricky Ricardo, you'd be dropping the "e", too.

Comment: @JeffSahol Ehh?

Comment: “Lucy! You got some splainin to do …”

Comment: “ *X* has a bewildering variety of pronunciations: depending on dialect and word position, it can sound like English’s *h*, *s*, *sh*, or *x*.” [link to Google cached page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OVadoe0LZBkJ:www.letsgo.com/9460-north_america-travel-guides-puerto_rico-basics-spanish_quick_reference-pronunciation-c&hl=en&gl=us&prmd=imvns&strip=1)

Comment: Yes, the *‑tain* > *‑tention* version is far easier to explain, as in *abstention, detention, irretention, manutention, obtention, retention, sustention, tention*, all due to that already happening in Latin *‑tenēre* > *‑tentiōnem*.

Comment: It has more to do with the lack of stress, which forced a change in the spelling!

Comment: There are plenty of other examples of dropped/altered vowels: Explain goes to Explanation much like Exclaim goes to Exclamation, and Pronounce goes to Pronunciation, and Maintain goes to Maintenance.

Comment: @J.R. these are the examples I couldn't think of

Comment: @Pureferret To understand the question mark see this FAQ: [What notation and symbols are commonly used here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#what-notation-and-symbols-are-commonly-used-here)

Comment: @ΜετάEd which question mark?

Comment: explanation isn't pronounced explaination.

Comment: @MattЭллен It is in my head.

Comment: Then learn to pronounce it correctly and the problem will go away!

Comment: @Pureferret The question mark before the word *explaination* which you removed and I restored. I thought you would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: The ***written*** word _explain_ contains an "i". The word _explain_ is pronounced /ɛk'splen/, with no i's. The derived noun _explanation_ is pronounced /ɛksplə'neʃən/, with different vowels. The spelling merely attempts (in no consistent way -- which is typical of English spelling) to represent the different vowels in the pronunciation. Warning: **Do Not** attempt to make sense of English spelling; go for the pronunciation because that's what's important. Spelling you just have to memorize, unless you get a PhD in historical linguistics.

Comment: For the same reason a vowel disappears from *detain* in *detention* or from *ordain* in *ordination*: because you won’t have a long vowel in an unstressed syllable.

Comment: Are you asking why the written 'i' disappears, or why the sound disappears? (In this case, writing seems to be following speech.)

Comment: John, where is the source for that pronunciation? I've never heard *explain* pronounced that way, it's always /ɪkˈspleɪ̯n/ or  /ɛkˈspleɪ̯n/ which certainly has an "i" sound to it. The hypothetical word "explan" would be pronounced distinctly.

Comment: That possibly explains the difference in spelling between maintain and maintenance. Richard D.

Comment: In French, explanation is *explication*.

Comment: @Hugh John Lawler _is_ the citation! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Expanding on ΜετάEd’s answer, the alternation between long /e:/ and short /a/ (or reduced version thereof, schwa or a mid-high vowel) is now frequent in Modern English (and harks back to the Great Vowel Shift).

So, alongside `expl[e:]n` ~ `expl[ə]nation`, you also have:

- `ex'pl[e:]n` ~ `expl[æ]natory`
- `ins[e:]ne` ~ `ins[æ]nity` (insane ~ insanity)
- `in[e:]ne` ~ `in[æ]nity` (inane ~ inanity)
- `n[e:]tion` ~ `n[æ]tionality` (nation ~ nationality)
- `[e:]ble` ~ `[ə]bility` (able ~ ability)

As you hunched and ΜετάEd pointed out, there is an orthographic oddity to *explain*, in that its /e:/ sound alternates with a lax vowel, but it is, orthographically, *ai*.  The nearest I can come to like examples is:

- *retain* ~ *retention* (this too is an etymological oddity, examples like *contend* ~ *contention*, *intend* ~ intention_, and so on, would lead one to expect *retend* ~ *retention*)
- *inveigh* ~ *invective* (where the origin of *eigh* is again etymologically odd, coming from *invehere*)

As the parenthetic comments make clear, these are as much oddities as the case you identified.

Answer (score 29):

The question should be: where did that *i* come from.

If we look at [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=explain&searchmode=none) we find the following: (emphasis mine)

> explain (v.) 
>   early 15c., from Latin explanare "to make level, smooth out;" also "to explain, make clear" 
>   **Originally explane**, spelling altered by influence of plain. Also see plane (v.2). In 17c., occasionally used more literally, of the unfolding of material things: Evelyn has buds that "explain into leaves" ["Sylva, or, A discourse of forest-trees, and the propagation of timber in His Majesties dominions," 1664]. Related: Explained; explaining; explains.

So it seems that the form *explane*, probably pronounced much like the current version, lost its final *e* and to reflect the pronunciation in the spelling, an i was added.

Comment: Like I say, don't expect English spelling to make sense. There is immense and largely random variation in the history and use of every word in the language. And of its spelling.

Comment: I don't expect it to make much sense, but sometimes there are - at least just below the surface - some nice factoids that can make the memorizing a bit easier to live with :)

Comment: Anything that helps memorization is unmixed good, as long as you don't try to stretch it to fit everything. As for other facts and other factoids, you can get all you need in David Crystal's _Cambridge Encyclopedias_, of Language, and of the English Language.

Comment: I'm a beginner... I just finished he _Little book of Language_ :)

Answer (score 7):

OEtmD says *explain* was “originally *explane*, spelling altered by influence of *plain*”.[¹](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=explain)

There have been many different ways that English words have been spelled to indicate pronunciation. The word *plain*, for example, has been spelled *plain, plane, plaine, playn, playne, pleyn, plegn, and plen*.[²](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/getent4.php?plen=5820&startset=49343132&dtext=dost&query=Plain)

Over time, spelling has become more consistent: for example, we use *plain* and *plane*, and have stopped using the others. But spelling has not been regularized to the point where every similar word uses the same spelling rule to indicate pronunciation.

There is not really a particular reason why we ended up with a particular spelling: or, rather, the reason is simply that the language evolved to be so.

Comment: Then why drop the "e"? ;)

Comment: Looking at examples in the OED, it seems that the word "explanation" is older (first documented use 1382) than the verb "explain" (1535).

Comment: OEtmD has *explain* early 15C (early 1400's).

Comment: Here's what Upward & Davidson 2011 say in their book, "The History of English Spelling": "More strikingly anomalous is explain, whose source, as is more apparent from the noun explanation, is the Latin explanare (Modern French expliquer ‘to explain’ derives from Latin explicare, whence also explicable); explain had the alternative form explane, but by not following the respelling of the cognate plain as plane in the 17th century, it now falsely suggests a relationship with unrelated complain (< Old French complaindre < Late Latin complangere)."

Comment: Playing with Middle English corpora, I found "explane" in "Treatises of fistula in ano" written by John Arderne (1307–1392), "I may plenerly explane tham in this litel boke" (page 3, line 23).

Answer (score 4):

The Latin stem explan- of explanare is to explain in English; the stress is on the vowel a and this leads to an enlargement, a becomes ai /ei/.
In explanation the stress is  on the next syllable. So we might guess the spelling would be explanaition, but obviously one has kept a spelling that is conforming to
the Latin noun explanation(em).