# Why is "irreparable" spelled without an "i"?

Tags: etymology, orthography, latin, roots

Pretty simple question, I think. Where does the "i" in "repair" go when spelling "reparable" or "irreparable" ? Is this just a "color"/"colour" type situation, or some deeper conspiracy?

Comment: In a little word with five syllable, leaving out the 'i' helps the pronunciation so the word does not rhyme with _wearable_.

Comment: The form ***irrepairable***, from the English verb, was used 16c.-17c. but seldom was seen after. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=irreparable

Comment: Related: [Why drop the “i” in “explanation”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78272/why-drop-the-i-in-explanation), [Why is it spelled “maintenance” and not “maintainance?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227497/why-is-it-spelled-maintenance-and-not-maintainance), [Why is the spelling of “pronounce” and “pronunciation” different?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/why-is-the-spelling-of-pronounce-and-pronunciation-different)

Answer (score 7):

Both words were borrowed from Latin via French.

The Latin verb is *reparare*. In modern French, it is spelled *réparer*; in Old French, when it was borrowed by English, it was *reparer*. The English word is first attested in the 14th century. Early forms in English were *repare, repayre, repeire, repeyre*, and *repaire*, probably because those all sounded very similar, at least in some periods.

As to why English eventually chose *repair* as its standard form, I don't think we know; it just "happened".

The word *irreparable* was also borrowed from Latin (*in-/irreparabilis*), via French *irreparable*, the French word first attested in the 12th century, the English in the 16th. It was sometimes also spelled *irrep**e**rable* in English, which probably also sounded similar.

As to why the *ai* spelling never occurred, we don't know. Perhaps it was because it is a long vowel, which is less likely to occur in unstressed syllables like *par* in *irreparable*, as opposed to stressed *pair* in *repair*.

Another hypothesis (of mine) is that in English the verb was confused with and fused with English *repair* "retire", from Latin *repatriare* ("return to one's fatherland"), via French *repairer*, which is semantically close and phonetically very similar, if not identical. Another, common word that pressures one into this direction is *pair*.

Comment: Related comment from a language-nerd friend of mine I just spoke with: "To repair in French is réparer. Irreparable  is irréparable. Def borrowed from French, just without the accents"

Comment: I won't give this as an answer because I don't know if it's *the* answer, but if you check [Wiktionary's etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/repair#Etymology_2) you will see that "repair" has two separate etymologies: one from French "reparer", as mentioned, with the meaning we're probably all thinking of, and one from French "repairer", this time with an <i>, with a meaning similar to "retreat". I find it quite plausible that due to the similar or identical pronunciation of these words in English, the spelling eventually merged.

Comment: @LjL: Ah, I was just writing that!